# Scala Pickling usage MyObject -> Array[Byte] -> MyObject

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I was trying to get into the new Scala Pickling library that was presented at the ScalaDays 2013: [Scala Pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling)

What I am really missing are some simple examples how the library is used.

I understood that I can pickle some object an unpickle it again like that:

```
import scala.pickling._

val pckl = List(1, 2, 3, 4).pickle
val lst = pckl.unpickle[List[Int]]
```

In this example, pckl is of the type Pickle. What exactly is the use of this type and how can I get for example get an Array[Byte] of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want wanted to pickle into bytes, then the code will look like this:

```
import scala.pickling._
import binary._         
val pckl = List(1, 2, 3, 4).pickle
val bytes = pckl.value
```

If you wanted json, the code would look almost the exact same with a minor change of imports:

```
import scala.pickling._
import json._         
val pckl = List(1, 2, 3, 4).pickle
val json = pckl.value
```

How the object is pickled depends on the import type that you chose under `scala.pickling` (being either `binary` or `json`).  Import `binary` and the `value` property is an `Array[Byte]`.  Import `json` and it's a json `String`.

Comment: Yep, cmbaxter is totally right. The type of the pickled representation is a subtype of `Pickle`. Selecting the `value` from the pickled representation gives you the type you'd expect, `Array[Byte]` for binary, `String` for JSON, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sometimes I get confused when Scala does something implicitly. I'm still used to the more explicit syntax like Java but I'm working on it. ;)

Comment: Could it be that IntelliJ doesn't understand, which type to use? I imported scala.pickling._ and binary._ and when I call .pickle on an object, IntelliJ tells me it is of the type Pickle, not BinaryPickle. Therefore it tells me that .value is of the type Pickle.this.type#ValueType. The compiler doesn't complain, for it the result type is BinaryPickle. My work-around: calling .pickle.asInstanceOf[BinaryPickle] for now so that it doesn't display an error in the IDE.

Comment: Very good point, thanks for bringing it up. A few days ago, we introduced a fix which we think should resolve this issue with IntelliJ. In a nutshell, the macros used in the pickling framework now have more precise type signatures that should be picked up by IntelliJ without IntelliJ having to expand the macro. Let us know if you continue to have issues with this!

Comment: I wish the documentation on the homepage was provided as an easier to read form rather than a cumbersome PDF meant for the university world. Pickling could be a nice library but I found it very lacking in that point.